# emacs `racket-mode` REPL not loading recognizing procedures

Tags: emacs, racket

I just installed `racket-mode` in my emacs 24.3, when I run the REPL via `racket-repl` command, the REPL starts correctly, but some of the racket procedures/functions aren't recognized. i.e

```
﻿> (class object%)
; class: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
> (enter! "test.rkt")
; enter!: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
```

﻿
The current value of the `racket-racket-program` variable is set to `Racket.exe`. On the other hand if I just run `Racket.exe` from the windows command line, then the `REPL` works as expected.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When you do a `racket-repl`, that REPL initially opens with the equivalent of `#lang racket/base`. At the prompt you could type `(require racket)` to get the bigger language, including the class stuff like `object%`.

  (There's an [open issue](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/issues/110) about this. Feel free to chime in there.)
- Instead of typing `(enter! "test.rkt")` at the prompt, try `,run test.rkt`.

  - In fact, the easiest way to do this is with an Emacs buffer open on test.rkt. Then you can press <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> a.k.a. `M-x racket-run`.

    (Note that this leaves point in the test.rkt buffer. If you prefer point to go to the REPL, instead you can use `M-x racket-run-and-switch-to-repl`, bound by default to <kbd>F5</kbd> like in DrRacket.)

TL;DR the most common use pattern with racket-mode is:

1. Visit a .rkt file in a buffer.
2. "Run" it with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> (or <kbd>F5</kbd>).
3. Explore in the REPL interactively as you wish.
4. Goto 2.

Comment: @soegaard I liked your answer before you deleted it; we were typing in parallel :)

Comment: Okay - I undeleted it.

Answer (score 2):

If your file contains `#lang racket` then the REPL picks up what language to use.
If no such line is present my guess is that `racket/base` is used -- and `object%` is not defined in `racket/base`.

Try entering this program:

```
#lang racket
(+ 1 2)
```

Then start the REPL and try your snippet again.